# After a git rebase, how to make foo and bar point to the same commit?

Tags: git, git-rebase

I think if branch `foo` points to commit `d89b430d`, and `bar` points to commit `554015b4`, then when we do:

```
git checkout foo
git rebase bar
```

and suppose it succeed without any conflict, then now `foo` will point to a new commit, while `bar` will point to the old one: `554015b4`

Is there a fast way to make `bar` point to the same place where `foo` is pointing to now?  Can it be done when we do `git rebase bar` and use some flag?  I wonder why `bar` is still pointing to `554015b4` but any good reason not to automatically make it point to where `foo` is pointing to?

By the way, if `bar` is not pointing to the tip, then isn't it one of the exception, that when you `git checkout <branch-name>`, then you would land on the tip.

The following is [an illustration from Atlassian](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing):

Before:
[image]

After you do:

```
git checkout feature
git rebase master
```

[image]

where the `master` is not pointing to the tip.

Comment: It *sounds* like you want to merge instead of rebase, but I need to be clear.  What does `git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all` look like before and after you do the rebase?

Comment: I am using SourceTree... I can see that after the `git rebase` command, foo and bar point to different places. By the way, many people use rebase to merge... they see that there are two ways to merge: either by merge or by rebase. And they may prefer rebase because it gives them a linear history

Comment: bar won't move because that's not the branch you are working on. git rebase will "recommit" (say) what is on foo **on top** of bar, but git won't mess with bar.

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout bar
git merge --ff-only foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Admitting that you have no changes in the working directory, you are in the exact case where the 3 following commands does the same things:

```
git rebase foo

git merge foo

git reset --hard foo
```

The last one is dangerous when you have changes to the working directory, so use it with precautions...

> I wonder why bar is still pointing to 554015b4 but any good reason not to automatically make it point to where foo is pointing to?

Because, you must understand (and never forget as it is one of the main git rule) that git only update/modify the ref of the branch you are on (ie that you have checkouted) leaving the others always intact.

Answer (score 0):

I see several options which should all result in the same final history.

Note that `git checkout foo; git rebase bar` can be shortened to `git rebase bar foo`.

##### Fast-forward merge

```
git rebase bar foo
git checkout bar
git merge --ff-only foo
```

##### Rebase

```
git rebase bar foo
git rebase foo bar
```

##### Fetch from local repo

```
git rebase bar foo
git fetch . foo:bar
```

##### Push to local repo

```
git rebase bar foo
git push . foo:bar
```

##### Recreate branch

```
git rebase bar foo
git branch -f bar foo
```

or to immediately switch to the branch

```
git rebase bar foo
git checkout -B bar foo
```

##### Hard reset

**This will DELETE any uncommitted changes!**

```
git rebase bar foo
git checkout bar
git reset --hard foo
```